# PQGrid autofocus cell

Tags: javascript, php, firefox

I have create a grid using PQGrid with 3 columns to show a month data.
last column is a checkbox and data type is bool.
when form load with new mode, it set focus to a text box in the form.
I need to set focus to first row checkbox in the PQGrid when update mode.

here is my code of creating grid.

```
gridObj.colModel = [
    { title : "Arrival Day", dataIndx : "arrivalDay", width :  10 , dataType : "string", editable: false, align: "center", resizable: false, sortable: false,  },
    { title : "Day of the week", dataIndx : "dayOfTheWeek", width :  10 , dataType : "string", editable: false, align: "center",  resizable: false, sortable: false, },
    { title : "Non-arrival", dataIndx: "colNoDelivery", width : 50 , type : "checkbox", dataType : "bool", editor: false, editable: true, align: "center", sortable: false, },
    { title : "DayCd", dataIndx: "colDayCdOfTheWeek", width : 0 , dataType : "string", sortable: false, hidden: true, },
];

// select option setting
gridObj.selectionModel = {
    type: 'cell',
    mode: 'single',
}

// data setting
gridObj.dataModel = {
    data : detailGridData
};
```

many thanks.